# sql performance with queries referencing objects from another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am curious to find out if there is a performance penalty accessing an object from another database on the same server vs accessing an object from the same database. For example, which one is faster

```
SELECT Anotherdb.dbo.GetFormattedData(@test)
```

OR

```
SELECT dbo.GetFormattedData(@test)
```

we are using sql server 2008.

Comment: You can use some sample data and test it

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a performance difference if you are on the same server.

The only time you should see a notable change in performance is if you are using a linked server and actually accessing a database via linked server.